# Keras/TensorFlow No registered NGraphVariable Opkernel

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

**Output error**:

`E tensorflow/core/framework/op_segment.cc:54] Create kernel failed: Not found: No registered 'NGraphVariable' OpKernel for GPU devices compatible with node {{node lstm_1/kernel}} = NGraphVariable[_class=["loc:@IsVariableInitialized"], container="", dtype=DT_FLOAT, just_looking=false, shape=[1,80], shared_name="", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()
    .  Registered:  device='CPU'`

#### Environment:

1. Sample [BiLSTM python code](https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-bidirectional-lstm-sequence-classification-python-keras/)
2. CUDA 9.2, CuDNN 7.4, Python 3.6, TensorFlow GPU 1.12, Keras 2.2.4
3. Ubuntu 18.10 with GTX1080 graphics

#### Question:

Is this error solved by compiling [NervanaSystems/ngraph](https://github.com/NervanaSystems/ngraph) from source?